# Subgroup notation on Wikipedia

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, notation

Surfing wikipedia about finite groups, I see a lot of notation similar to that found [in this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group#Subgroup_structure) (image below). 
Its meaning is not clear to me and I didn't find an explanation on wikipedia. Could anyone elaborate?

> [image]

Comment: Is your question "what do symbols like $L_3(3)$, $M_{11}$, and $A_5$ mean"?

Comment: No, my issue is with $2^{1+24}.Co_1$ as an example. Also the lower case $.$ that are used.

Comment: Thanks, the question is clear now. Perhaps you could mention this in the question itself.

Comment: This is the notation used in the book "ATLAS of Finite Groups". $2^{1+24}.{\rm Co}_1$ means a group with a normal subgroup $N$ that is an extraspecial group of order $2^{25}$ and such that the quotient group $G/N$ is isomorphic to the first Conway simple group, ${\rm Co}_1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I believe your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @DerekHolt: would you like to convert your comment into an answer to remove this question from the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Derek Holt, this is the notation used in the book "ATLAS of Finite Groups".

In particular, $2^{1+24}.Co_1$ means a group with a normal subgroup $N$ that is an extraspecial group of order $2^{25}$ and such that the quotient group $G/N$ is isomorphic to the first Conway simple group, $Co_1$.